# Opening a .zbd file?

Tags: file-management, file-extension

I have a .zbd file with sensitive information on it.

I have downloaded the ZoomBrowser from Canon, it does not recognize it as a file.

I downloaded the Zebedee Secure Tunnel, but that just creates a tunnel, and is not a file viewer.

I have downloaded a number of free file viewers, but none seem to open this file.

Any assistance you could give is immensely appreciated.

Comment: So what was it created with?

Comment: I am unsure. This was a disk given to me upon being discharged from the military 16 years ago.

Comment: Ask the military?

Comment: I did. Technology has changed and they no longer know.

Comment: You might think about asking in the retrocomputing chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=retrocomputing.stackexchange.com

Comment: assuming you're on Windows, given the programs you've tried.  You may be able to gather hints by hex-dumping the file and looking for strings.  If you have powershell available, you can use ```Format-hex <filename>.zbd``` to do this.  It's not likely to do much with whatever data is there, but there may be some strings that help identify whatever created the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Online TrID File Identifier](https://mark0.net/onlinetrid.html) or [Filext Viewer](https://filext.com/online-file-viewer.html) to find out the format of your zbd file.

Most .zbd files are audio files in RIFF format. Just open your zbd file in the Windows Editor and check if the first 4 bytes are `RIFF`.
If the first bytes are `\x00` (zero bytes), then it is a texture image file.